# iPhone Facebook SDK: failed to post status the second time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, sdk

It happens even with the sample projects from the github. The first time it worked fine in updating my status, but the second time debugger always shows an error_code = 1, and error_msg = "An unknown error occured". Yes I clicked the "Get Permission" button first.

And this is the sample project. Posting stories worked fine, although the application displays the same error message.

Could this be a result of some facebook changes?

Please help!

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

```
FBSession *mFbSession;
```

In .m file

```
self.mFbSession = nil;
mFbSession = [init....];
```

Try setting your session value to nil before initializing or before reassigning from shared session instance.